# Snapcraft: Cannot find executable

Tags: snapcraft

I'm trying to create a snap package, and have gotten `snapcraft` to build one.

However, when trying to run the binary, after installing my freshly built snap, I get:

```
cannot snap-exec: cannot exec "/snap/foobar/x1/snap/command-chain/snapcraft-runner": no such file or directory
```

The `snapcraft-runner` file exists, so I assume the error is because this one can't find my binary.

Here's the relevant part from my `snapcraft.yaml`

```yaml
confinement: devmode
base: bare
build-base: core18

parts:
  foobar:
    plugin: dump
    source: bin/foobar_x64.tgz

apps:
  foobar:
    command: foobar
```

I'm building a statically linked binary outside of snap, so I really don't need anything inside. It's just so people can keep it updated with a package manager and I suppose to confine it (later).

The source `tgz` just contains one single binary `foobar`. My assumption is that it's not in the PATH and that's why it doesn't find it. I've tried to move it into `bin/` with an organize directive, I've tried to change the command to various things such as `${SNAP}/foobar` and `/foobar`.

All of these get rejected during the build, because it complains it can't find the binary, or says the command has illegal characters.

`./foobar` behave the same as just `foobar`, it builds, and then doesn't work.

The binary also also definitely copied and executable:

```
$ file /snap/foobar/x1/foobar 
/snap/foobar/x1/foobar: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, no section header

$ ls -la /snap/foobar/x1/foobar 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 1786200 Jul  5 21:00 /snap/foobar/x1/foobar
``


How can I get it to find my executable?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed this issue.

This wrapper can be disabled, and then it seems to find a/the binary

In your snapcraft.yaml under `apps -> yourapp` add `adapter: none`

E.g.

```yaml
apps:
  foobar:
    command: foobar
    adapter: none
```